# Prove $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac{n}{n+1}$ by induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, induction

Using induction, prove that

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac{n}{n+1}$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that `1/1*2+1/2*3+...` is interpreted as $\frac{1}{1}\cdot 2 + \frac{1}{1}\cdot 3 + \dots$.  You presumably mean instead `1/(1*2) + 1/(2*3)+...` which is $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2} + \frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\dots$.  When typing without proper typesetting, parenthesis are important.  Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a primer on how to type in $\LaTeX$ and MathJax on this site in order to make your equations easier to read and make sure that there is no potential confusion in meaning of equations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove the following equality using mathematical induction:](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638366/prove-the-following-equality-using-mathematical-induction)

Answer (score 2):

Assume induction statement

\begin{equation}
P(n): \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i(i+1)}  = \frac{n}{n+1}
\end{equation}

For $n=1$,

\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^1 \frac{1}{i(i+1)}  = \frac{1}{1(1+1)} = \frac {1}{1+1}
\end{equation}

Then assume $P(n)$ is true and $n \geq 1$. We must show the following induction statement to be true

\begin{equation}
P(n+1): \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)}  = \frac{n+1}{(n+1)+1}
\end{equation}

Since we are assuming $P(n)$ is true,

\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)}  &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i(i+1)} + \frac {1}{(n+1)(n+1+1)} \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1} + \frac {1}{(n+1)(n+1+1)} \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1} + \frac {1}{(n+1)(n+2)} \\
&= \frac{n(n+2) + 1}{(n+1)(n+2)} \\
&= \frac{n^2 + 2n + 1}{(n+1)(n+2)} \\
&= \frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)(n+2)} \\
&= \frac{n+1}{n+2} \\
&= \frac{n+1}{(n+1)+1} \\
\end{align}

Thus $P(n+1)$ is true so $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i(i+1)}  = \frac{n}{n+1}$ is true for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $1\over (n+1)(n+2)$$=$${1\over n+1}-{1\over n+2}$. The result should immediately follows from this and your induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

To show:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 {k (k+1)} = \frac n {n+1} \tag{*}
$$
Base case $n = 1$: obvious.

Assume (*) is true for $n$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac 1 {k (k+1)} &= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 {k (k+1)} + \frac 1 {(n+1) (n+2)} \\
&= \frac n {n+1} + \frac 1 {(n+1) (n+2)} \tag{by IH} \\
&= \frac {n(n+2) + 1} {(n+1) (n+2)} \\
&= \frac {n^2+2n + 1} {(n+1) (n+2)}  \\
&= \frac {(n + 1)^2} {(n+1) (n+2)} \\
&= \frac {(n + 1)} {(n+2)} \\
\end{align}
$$
which shows that (*) is true for $n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Base Case**:

Suppose $n = 1$.  Then,

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{i(i + 1)} = \frac{1}{2} = \frac{n}{n + 1} $$

Thus, the proposition holds for $n = 1$.

**Inductive Step**:

Suppose $$ \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{i(i + 1)} = \frac{n}{n + 1} $$

For arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Then we can deduce the following at $n + 1$:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1} \frac{1}{i(i + 1)} &= \frac{n}{n + 1} + \frac{1}{(n + 1)(n + 2)} \\
&= \frac{n}{n + 1} + \frac{1}{n + 1} - \frac{1}{n + 2} \\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{n + 2} \\
&= \frac{n + 1}{n + 2} \\
&= \frac{n + 1}{(n + 1) + 1}
\end{align*}

Thus, $ \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{i(i + 1)} = \frac{n}{n + 1} $ holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.