# Why is $\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n^2+n}=\frac{k}{k+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n^2+n}=\frac{k}{k+1}$$

I don't think that this summation requires too much context as this is a Q&A site, but I was just wondering why the summation is evaluated so nicely. I don't have too much knowledge and creativity in evaluating sums, so is there a bunch of equations that will make this make sense instantly? If so, I haven't found it on the internet.

$\frac{k}{k+1}$ looks a lot like the formula for the geometric series. I was wondering if $$\dfrac{1}{r}\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right)=\frac{1}{-r^2+r}$$ had anything to do with this problem.

Comment: You could have a look, for example, at: [What is the formula for $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/286024) or [Prove the following equality using mathematical induction: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac{n}{n+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/638366).

Comment: Proof by induction doesn’t scratch that itch as much as derivation does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you to Surb for that hint.
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n^2+n}&=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\\ &=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n+1}
\\ &=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{k-1}+\frac{1}{k}\\\\ &\phantom{\frac{1}{1}+}-\Big(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{k-1}+\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k+1}\Big)\end{align*}$$

Everything cancels out except for $\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{k+1}=\frac{k}{k+1}$.

Comment: You’re right. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{n^2+n}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Answer (score -1):

The problem of this *telescopic series* was posed in Finnish Matriculation Exam, 2015 Spring, A-level mathematics, Problem set 15*, worth 9 points instead of ordinary 6. The problem set, question b) itself gives hints to the intuition behind it:

b.) Find $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $$ \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{a}{n}+\frac{b}{n+1}$$

The solution starts by expanding the terms:

$$ \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = {}^{n+1)} \frac{a}{n}+ {}^{n)} \frac{b}{n+1}$$
$$ \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{(a+b)n + a}{n(n+1)} $$

We have a linear system, we need to satisfy both $a+b = 0$ and $a=1$ which implies $b=-1$, the hint Surb gave.